# What does it mean 'package limitation current' on a MOSFET datasheet?

Tags: mosfet, current, temperature

I was looking at the datasheet for IRF1405 and got really excited when I saw 169A @ 25C!
Then I started scrolling down and it says 'package limitation current is 75A'.

Does that mean the maximum current I can get out of this MOSFET is 75A? And what does it mean when it says 'package limitation'?
Are they talking about the maximum temperature that the package can handle before it melts which is why it can only take 75A?

Comment: You aren't getting anywhere 75A in my experience. Even if you have a ton of cooling. Always always try and calculate the actual heating rather than trusting those datasheet current numbers. Treat those numbers as dimensionless metrics that are only useful for comparing against the datasheets of other MOSFETs.

Comment: would you like to share your experience?

Comment: Even if the package wasn't a limitation, no realistically sized heat sink could keep it at 25ºC while dissipating 300W. Also the SOA graph shows that 169A is only safe when the FET is turned hard on (when you probably don't want to be dissipating 300W). It is a theoretical figure that practical designs should avoid.

Comment: A pulse at @ 680A and 6V would be pretty exciting from Fig 1 !

Answer (score 2):

Do some more reading of the datasheets. Devices like MOSFETs can be offered in several packages, from large TO-247 style to SMD with a small metal tab that solders to the board. So the package used determines the amount of metal area to dissipate heat. For many popular MOSFETs the change shows up as a modified part number, with the base part number the same.

This way designers know the performance specs because of past usage. Voltage, speed and gate capacitance do not change, they just have to de-rate the wattage it can dissipate if going from a TO-247/TO-220 package to a surface mount. The best way to do this is to lower the current rating of smaller packages.

It makes sense because not every application will need the large TO-247 package as a high-side switch or a powerful SMPS. On many boards point-of-use switches and local SMPS may need a fraction of the wattage the TO-247 can handle, yet the designer wants to stay with known good part numbers.

On a smaller scale the humble BS170 MOSFET is offered in a TO-92 package, and a de-rated version is offered in a SOT-23 SMD 3-pin. The base part number '170' is prepended with MMBF. The TO-92 package can be pulsed at 1200 mA 830 mW, while the SOT-23 package is limited to 800 mA 300mW.

All of this info can be on the same datasheet, but clearly defined by different packages, prefixes and suffixes, and "package limitation current".